# Error using github REST API to change description of a release - if description contains parentheses

Tags: git, groovy, github-api

I am using groovy to run the following command that updates a release description on github:

```
"curl -v -i -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -H 'Authorization: token 111111122222222222222222222' 'https://api.github.com/repos/company/repoName/releases/$id' -d '$API_JSON'"
```

API_JSON contains a short log of git commits:

```
{"body":
    "description=Committer name (35):
    JIRA-1111 - SOME COMMENTS -  GIT_HASH on DATE-TIME"}
```

The issue is that if the comments have parentheses as in `(SOME COMMENTS)` the command fails with

```
Stdout: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I've tried a using a regex to replace parentheses with their contents (if content is not numerical) but that caused an error as well.

```
Stdout: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Groovy script to execute the curl command:

```
        //replace new lines
        description = description.replace('\n','<br/>')
        //remove parentheses and their contents if non numerical
        description = description.replaceAll("\\((?=[^)]*[a-zA-Z ])[^)]+?\\)","<br/>");

        def API_JSON = sprintf ('{"body": "%s"}', description);
        def githubCommand =  "curl -v -i -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -H 'Authorization: token 1111111111111111111111111111111’ 'https://api.github.com/repos/company/repo/releases/$id' -d '$API_JSON'"

        String[] commands = ["/bin/bash", "-c", githubCommand]

        def processBuilder=new ProcessBuilder(commands)
```

Also - an error occurs if there's a new line in the comments but using a regex to to replace `\n` with `<\br>` fixed the issue and the release description was updated correctly if there are no parentheses.

Update: Passing a clean array of arguments to ProcessBuilder, did no work (even without any parentheses it did not update the github release description)

```
String postData = /{"body":"I'm (not) sure"}/
String[] command = ['curl', '-v', '-i', '-s','-X', 'POST', '-H','Content-Type:application/json', '-H', 'Authorization: token 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 'https://api.github.com/repos/company/reppo/releases/$id', '-d', postData]
def process = new ProcessBuilder(command).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
println process.text
```

The command exited successfully but it did not do anything (no output either)

Comment: How exactly do you execute the `curl` command?

Comment: Added to my question

Comment: Your last attempt has a fancy quote character `’` that closes the `11111’` part. That is not a proper quote (`'`). Look at how syntax coloring is off after it.

Comment: The fancy quote character was added when I edited the real token with 1111.... When I run with the original value it doesn't show the fancy character.

Comment: `'{"body": "I'm not sure"}'` is still improperly quoted. You are using both single and double quotes within your string, you need to use [slashy strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) (`/{"body": "I'm not sure"}/` as explained in my answer), or alternatively [triple single quoted strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) `'''{"body": "I'm not sure"}'''`

Comment: It still doesn't work even without the quotes (I updated the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is improperly quoted, so your problem is not just with parentheses within your data.

The following fails with a similar error:
<sub>(I'm using `httpbin.org` instead of GitHub so anyone can test, removing irrelevant `curl` arguments for brevity, and [slashy strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) for data because it contains both single and double quotes, `'` and `"`)</sub>

```groovy
def postData = /{"comment":"I'm (not) sure"}/
def command = "curl -s https://httpbin.org/post -d '${postData}'"
// At this point the command is already broken, the following will fail
String[] commands = ["/bin/bash", "-c", command]
def process = new ProcessBuilder(commands).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
println process.text
```

The string that is passed as argument for `bash` is the following:

```
curl -s https://httpbin.org/post -d '{"comment":"I'm (not) sure"}'
```

The quote in the middle breaks our string, and the resulting command line is rejected by bash (exactly as it would be if executed from a shell):

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

However if you pass a clean array of arguments to your `ProcessBuilder`, it works:

```groovy
String postData = /{"comment":"I'm (not) sure"}/
String[] command = ['curl', '-s', '-i', '-H' ,'Content-Type:application/json', 'https://httpbin.org/post', '-d', postData]
def process = new ProcessBuilder(command).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
println process.text
```

Alternatively, you can do HTTP POST with Groovy without curl:

```groovy
def postData = /{"foo":"I'm (not) sure"}/
def baseUrl = new URL('https://httpbin.org/post')
def connection = baseUrl.openConnection()
connection.with {
    setDoOutput(true)
    setRequestMethod('POST')
    setRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    outputStream.withWriter { it << postData }
    println content.text
}
```

Comment: I've tried the first method but I got an error without any parentheses:

Comment: The alternative method worked.  thank you @Hugues M.!